# Find Docker-In-Docker Bind Mount Path in WSL2

Tags: docker

Normally, when finding a bind-mount path for the overlay2 driver with Docker-in-Docker, I can do it via the following:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
$ apt-get install jq -y
$ mount_point=$(docker inspect $HOSTNAME | jq -r '.[0].GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir')
$ echo "$mount_point"
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c68a6fc53a27d6347e691a52bdd792094a7a4fdc65041b387d1ea38607ba999d/merged
$ mkdir hello && cd hello
$ echo "sample contents" > file
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash \
    -v "$mount_point/hello":/hello \
    -w /hello \
    gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
$ ls
# nothing
```

For everything besides WSL2, this will properly mount my files. However, for WSL2, it seems the bind mounts are present under a different location. If my attached WSL2 distro name is `Ubuntu-22.04`, I can find a list of unique IDS under `/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/`:

```bash
$ ls /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/
13a7bc88b63d361f5752d7ef3f5c96cd262ef580e6f435cced6bd10ec82842b0  692b88d87549cc6cb71d70e56b24d64d46c6e4f3b54611d635e407941a34d5da
21241f82d3c1e170eae05d87ed4fe9493165603a5f20f4decc5da0695296a22b  71329c4cc6e32171553fa81d044eb31d1a3aac52ba9376c4a99f4505c494cf5b
2af2028475f25893cbe6ae56fd41a5060323a05cf2de361ca5cd788882ab124e  9f9cdad793414edd07516ebe0fef99bea77a67d7033bcce9e6e2636fc52d206f
40072ee5313e41a68b132298796cbec4d044881a473056704dbaf45732b96709  e9b0d5f175dde593817759ef48c2ea4be074dd6fd7dde1e5ee0051f1cbbb36e7
449de67da5b95f36f74bf415852073e587a6f2f5acffecd8470687a065aa9a24  fd27f4eaa94fe2d4e43106f3751004bf816189bf06237c658a0c8e7aec6e54c8
67aa8dec46ea42423b4090c10503d733f4ff4c1eb43cb8e31f040c84cafba60c
```

Now, if I use a bindmount for the initial load, I can find the file as the mount point in the container, so at least I can get files relative to a mount point (but not very reliably). Run on the WSL2 host:

```bash
$ find /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04 -name clippy.toml
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/b7371a7ca29bc7acbea2f7cebdf0d5b452a4fadd8af16a733896e7dccbd49e3a/clippy.toml
/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/0157aea7f7f54b90e62c5810422a2535f5513005a8db7001cf10c7753d3dc6fb/clippy.toml
```

This isn't straightforward if more than 1 container or bind mount exists with that file, however. Also, none of the hashes for the container match the Docker inspect or the hostname. Now, run on the container:

```bash
$ correct_id=b7371a7ca29bc7acbea2f7cebdf0d5b452a4fadd8af16a733896e7dccbd49e3a
$ echo $HOSTNAME
dadd6ab5f853
$ docker inspect $HOSTNAME| grep b737
# nothing
```

So there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to find that file. Also, for any files outside a bind mount, there doesn't seem to be a way to find their path. At least, however, the correct WSL2 bind mount location does work if passed into the container:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash \
    -v /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/b7371a7ca29bc7acbea2f7cebdf0d5b452a4fadd8af16a733896e7dccbd49e3a/:"$PWD" \
    -w "$PWD" gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
$  ls
CHANGELOG.md        Cargo.lock  LICENSE-APACHE  README.md  ci           crosstool-ng  docker  rustfmt.yml  target
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  Cargo.toml  LICENSE-MIT     assets     clippy.toml  deny.toml     docs    src          xtask
```

But how do I find say, a file in the container at `/hello/file`, which was created inside the container run within WSL2?

I should also mention this is Docker Desktop for Windows being shared into the WSL Ubuntu distro. Docker was not installed inside the distro and then used without iptables.

Comment: have you tried using bind mount for specific paths of your choosing? instead of relying on a random path generated at the container runtime

Comment: Yes, it doesn't mount unless the path is identical to the host and has been shared from the host. So if I share `/path/to/x:/path/to/x` and then inside the first layer, do `/path/to/x:/path/to/x`, it mounts, but if I do `/path/to/x:/y`, it doesn't at either level unless I use the `MergedDir` (which is a good reason why `MergedDir` exists). Also, this doesn't work for data created in the container on WSL2 (say, at `/hello`), but it does for Docker on Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're expiriencing the first issue, have you tried relative paths? regarding the second one, have you tried creating a subdirectory in the mounted dir? lets say your mounted directory inside the container is `/y` then your self created file or dir is `/y/hello` and depending on the environment you're developing in (container, locally, linux in general) change the path (this is common, not just for your case). would that work?

Comment: The first issue is pretty clear: that's how docker-in-docker works, because you need to provide paths relative to the docker host. This approach is consistent among all container engines except on WSL2 I've seen with overlay2 drivers. As for the latter: I'm asking because the goal is so people can use data in docker that is not a subdirectory of a bind mount from the host, because we don't control what they mount. So that's not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDs in `docker-desktop-bind-mounts` are calculated like this [1]:

```
realpath /tmp/ | tr -d '\n' | sha256sum

=> e9671acd244849c57167c658fa2f969752048f7ab184a3dcf5c46cb4d56ae124
```

So if you started docker from inside the `Ubuntu-22.04` WSL2 distro, that hash inside `docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/` maps to `/tmp` inside that WSL2 distro.

[1] https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9823#issuecomment-866776203